Preliminaries for Chapter 4. Surfaces of Griffiths-Harris Algebraic Geometry
I am looking for a book on complex surfaces that has a topological (or differential-geometric) viewpoint, in the sense that the language of schemes is avoided, and the classic topology is used instead of the Zariski topology. (So, I am trying to avoid Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry or Beauville's Complex Algebraic Surfaces.) What I've found is Griffiths-Harris's book Principles of Algebraic Geometry. Its 4th chapter deals with complex surfaces. However, it has too many chapters before chapter 4. Are there some (sub)chapters that are unnecessary to read Chapter 4? Below is the table of contents.
Chapter 0. Foundational Material (This chapter seems to be necessary.)
Chapter 1. Complex Algebraic Varieties (This chapter also seems to be necessary, possibly except for section 5?)

Divisors and Line Bundles

Some Vanishing Theorems and Corollaries

Algebraic Varieties

The Kodaira Embedding Theorem

Grassmannians


Chapter 2. Riemann Surfaces and Algebraic Curves (I am expecting that maybe some sections in Chapters 2 and 3 are not necessary for Chapter 4)

Preliminaries

Abel's Theorem

Linear System on Curves

Plucker Formulas

Correspondences

Complex Tori and Abelian Varieties

Curves and Their Jacobians


Chapter 3. Further Techniques

Distributions and Currents

Applications of Currents to Complex Analysis

Chern Classes

Fixed-Point and Residue Formulas

Spectral Sequences and Applications


Also I want to know (if any) more books on complex surfaces.

You might try Compact Complex Surfaces by Barth-Hulek-Peters-van de Ven.

You absolutely need to be comfortable/familiar with the language of divisors and line bundles, and some familiarity with curve theory will be required, along with the basics from Chapter 0 (forms, sheaves, bundles, Kähler forms, Hodge decomposition). You will need most of Chapter 1. You most likely don't need Chapter 3 other than to know about the Chern classes of vector bundles.
